# VB.Net how to use a ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, reportviewer

I am new at using a `ReportViewer` and wondering how to use it. All the posts I read mention the use of a `Datagridview` which is than transferred to a Report. I am wondering do I have to make a `Datagridview` first to send the data to a `ReportViewer`?

I have an archive over several years that I want to be able to print. The data is in a `MSAccess` database. I want to make the connection to the database, create the dataset and pass it on to the form with `ReportViewer`. I want to code the connection and dataset, since I am not always using the same databasw

Comment: Why not use Microsoft Access and its excellent report builder?

Comment: @Gustav because I am creating an application in VB.NET

Comment: @jmcilhinney I read the suggested article however I need to be independent on the connection because I am not always using the same database.